# Color a 4*4 grid with 5 colors so that all colors are used and each column and each row have at most 2 colors.

Tags: logic

I tried to solve it by realizing that at least 2 corners had to be the same color. I tried to solve it by using guess-and-check, but found that it was impossbile to incorporate the 4 and 5th colors. Is this question impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put colors red, green, blue, and yellow in the four diagonal boxes.  Color all the other boxes hot pink.  Diagram follows:

RPPP
PGPP
PPBP
PPPY

Comment: Be my guest: `:-)` $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\color{#f42}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare\\ \hline
\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{green}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare\\ \hline
\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{blue}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare\\ \hline
\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{#f0c}\blacksquare&\color{#fd0}\blacksquare\\ \hline
\end{array}$$